# How to read the user email address in HP QC Script Editor?

Tags: vbscript, scripting, hp-quality-center

Inside the HP Quality Center Scripting Editor, I can access current user info (like user name or full name) with the "user" object.

How do I access the current user E-Mail address property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in QC workflow documentation, the user object only had these properties: FullName, IsInGorup and UserName.

Since this is the case, you need access to the full user data, which you can get by using the customization metadata exposed by OTA.

To get user info, you need to get the **CustomizationUser** object which has an **Email** property.
Here is a sample from documentation on iterating over the users list:

```
Sub ListUsers()

  Dim custUsers As CustomizationUsers
  Dim USR As CustomizationUser
  Dim UList As List

  Set custUsers = tdc.Customization.Users

  Set UList = custUsers.Users
  Debug.Print UList.Count

  Dim maxU%, uCnt%

  maxU = 5

  For Each USR In UList
    uCnt = uCnt + 1
    With USR
        Debug.Print .name & ", " & .Email
    End With
    If uCnt > maxU Then Exit For
  Next USR

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    ErrHandler err
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Based on your code I finally came up with this:

  Set td = tdconnection

  Set cust = td.customization

  Set usrs = cust.Users

  Set usr = usrs.User(user.UserName)

  sEMail = usr.Email